# Can you use "What is today's day?"

Tags: vocabulary, questions, time

> “What day is it today?”

For the same meaning, can you say “what is today’s day?” Consulting a definition of Merriam-Webster’s for ‘[day](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/day)’ –– one of the seven time periods that make up a week –– there seems no wrongness to use the sentence.

Comment: In everyday speech, it's often quite common to just ask, "What's today?" even though this is an ambiguous question that could be answered, by any of "Friday", "the 22nd", "Memorial Day" etc.  But in context it usually suffices.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Saying “*what is today’s day?*” sounds awkward and is not really used. There is nothing wrong with saying “*What day is it today?*”, which would mean that someone is asking what day of the week it is today for example, Monday or Saturday.

Answer (score 0):

**I agree with @Tristan.**

You could also say. "What day of the week is it today?"

---

**Note**

“What is today's day?” would never be said by a native speaker.